# Node.js multible get functions with different parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have the following Node.js Express routes

```
app.get('/api/admin/elements/:type', elements.getElementsByType);
app.get('/api/admin/elements/:_id', elements.getElement);
```

the elements funtions are:

```
getElementsByType : function(req, res) {
element.find({
    type : req.params.type
}, function(err, elements) {
    if (err) {
    return err;
    }
    res.json(elements);
});
},
getElement : function(req, res) {
var file = "/thatulborooj-data/elements/" + req.params._id + ".json";
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) {
    res.json([]);
    } else {
    res.json(JSON.parse(obj));
    }
});
}
```

when I all `$http.get('/api/admin/elements/' + scope.element._id)` fro angularJS it always all the first get, how can I make difference between them or set parameter type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

express.js **doesn't know** the name of the variable that you pass to it, because it is a webserver which listen to some addresses.

In your case the first route says:

If someone goes on `/api/admin/elements/{{whatever}}` call the function `elements.getElementsByType()` and assign *whatever* to the variable `type`

The second route says the same thing, just to call another function and assign the value to the var `_id`.

A possible solution is to have two different routes:

```
app.get('/api/admin/elements/type/:type', elements.getElementsByType);
app.get('/api/admin/elements/id/:_id', elements.getElement);
```

Another possible solution is, if you are sure `id` is **always** an `int` and `type` is **never** an int is to call just one function and choose what to do checking the param type:

```
app.get('/api/admin/elements/:value', elements.getElementsByType);

getElementsByType : function(req, res) {
if (isNaN(req.params.value)) {
  // this is a type
} else {
  //this is an id
}
```

But I want to highlight it is important you understand why your example doesn't work.

I cannot explain how web works in just one answer, but let me highlight some things:

express.js listens on your server to request to a [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)), as a [webserver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server). You can say to express.js which routes you want to listen: all routes that aren't specified will reply with 404 (or 405 if you ask for a method that doesn't exist on a resource that exists, like POST on `/api/admin/elements/{{whatever}}` in your example).

So, when you specify a route, you have two components:

a fixed part, which is the address, and it is always the same (like `/api/admin/elements/`), and a part which value can change.

You say to express.js which part can change using the `:` notation. For express.js, whatever is in an URL between the `/:` and the next `/` has to be passed in the `req.params` object with the name you specify.

Let's do some examples:

```
/a/:a/b/:b/c/:c
```

This address will response to each call you do to `/a/{{param1}}/b/{{param2}}/c/{{param3}}

So you will have a `req.params` object with these 3 values:

```
req.param = {
  a: 'param1',
  b: 'param2',
  c: 'param3',
}
```

You do not like *a*, *b*, and *c* as names? Me neither, so let's change that:

```
/a/:artemis/b/:betelgeuse/c/:cassidy
```

Then the req.params object will be:

```
req.param = {
  artemis: 'param1',
  betelgeuse: 'param2',
  cassidy: 'param3',
}
```

But for express.js it is **the same thing**, it cannot choose what it is basing only on the value.

Now, an example a bit more complicated:

if you have

`/a/:a` and `/a/b` for express.js can be a bit confusing (but also for whoever uses your APIs, so **please do not do this**).

Now, how this works is up to the order you declared the routes.

If you did `/a/:a` and then `/a/b` the function associated to `/a/b` will never be called. express.js takes the address requested and check each route if it has a match. So if you call `/a/b` express.js finds `/a/:a` (that means `an /a/ and a thing after this` and thinks the `b` is a valid value for the variable `a`).

But if you declare the `/a/b` before the `/a/:a` express.js will reach before the `/a/b` (that means a route that is exactly `/a/b`) then it will be matched first.

Comment: oh my god, bunch of words :<

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is perfect

Comment: Excellent detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `_id` should match an ObjectId, you can make the route handler explicitly match those:

```
app.get('/api/admin/elements/:_id([a-f0-9]{24})', elements.getElement);
app.get('/api/admin/elements/:type', elements.getElementsByType);
```

Just be sure that the `_id` route is declared *before* the (more general) `type` route.

Caveat: this breaks if you use types that match ObjectId's.